# Getting ad status without other meta data

Tags: facebook-ads-api

Is there a way to get Facebook ad status (adgroup_status & ad_status) without getting all the targeting and creative information. From the documentation it seems like one can only get status when making the following call  /{adgroup-id} which returns all the meta data about the ad.

The above call you return the following data

```js
{
   "id":"6004196911039",
   "data":{
      "adgroups":{
         "6004196911039":{
            "adgroup_id":6004196911039,
            "ad_id":6004196911039,
            "campaign_id":6003417011234,
            "name":"test",
            "ad_status":4,
            "adgroup_status":4,
            "bid_type":1,
            "max_bid":"30",
            "bid_info":{
               "1":"30"
            },
            "account_id":368811234,
            "id":"6004196911039",
            "creative_ids":[
               6004196615439
            ],
            "targeting":{
               "countries":[
                  "US"
               ],
               "friends_of_connections":[
                  {
                     "id":"6004008089439",
                     "name":null
                  }
               ]
            },
            "start_time":null,
            "end_time":null,
            "updated_time":1328021899
         }
      },
      "creatives":{
         "6004196615439":{
            "type":25,
            "action_spec":"{'action.type':'like', 'post':10150420410887685}",
            "related_fan_page":1,
            "cluster_id":6004008089439,
            "name":"Sponsored story #6004196615439",
            "run_status":1,
            "preview_url":"http:\/\/www.facebook.com\/ads\/api\/creative_preview.php?cid=6004196615439",
            "count_current_adgroups":2,
            "id":"6004196615439",
            "creative_id":"6004196615439"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

Getting just the status would be less costly for groups of ads.

Answer (score 0):

Answering for other folks who might be searching for the answer.

Yes, you can do this by providing specific fields you want to query as part of your call, for example you can append this to your call:

?fields=adgroup_status,ad_status

And the graph API will only return the specific fields.